# NRE when using array initializer in object initializer

Tags: c#, .net

I'm observing some strange behavior (tested in VS2013) when using array initializer in the following case:

```
    class A
    {
        public List<int> Items { get; set; }
    }

    void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // (1) it compiles, but failing with NRE in runtime
        var a = new A { Items = { 1, 2, 3 } };

        // (2) it does not compile, as expected
        List<int> b = { 1, 2, 3 };
    }
```

Actually I would expect a compiler error in the case (1), the same that I have in case (2): `Can only use array initializer expressions to assign to array types. Try using a new expression instead.` But the case (1) compiles without any problem and expectable fails with `NullReferenceException` when running. Can someone explain why compiler allows the case (1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the relevent quote from the C# spec (version 5, section 7.6.10.2):

> A member initializer that specifies a collection initializer after the equals sign is an initialization of an embedded collection. **Instead of assigning a new collection to the field or property, the elements given in the initializer are added to the collection referenced by the field or property.** The field or property must be of a collection type that satisfies the requirements specified in §7.6.10.3.

So because you're using a collection initializer *inside an object initializer*, the behaviour is different, and this code:

```
var a = new A { Items = { 1, 2, 3 } };
```

Compiles down to something like this (You can verify this by looking at the IL):

```
var a = new A();
a.Items.Add(1);
a.Items.Add(2);
a.Items.Add(3);
```

This of course throws a NullReferenceException because `Items` is null.

You can fix the crash by adding a constructor to class `A`:

```
class A
{
    public List<int> Items { get; set; }
    public A() { Items = new List<int>(); }
}
```